# Why am I getting an EOFException in my Java code?

Tags: java, java-io, datainputstream, eofexception

I am trying to read a csv file and having the output shown in the console. However, I can't understand why I am getting an end of file exception and nothing is being shown in the console?

The Exception message is:

```
java.io.EOFException
at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:197)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:609)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:564)
at ByteIO.main(ByteIO.java:17)
```

My code is:

```
import java.io.*;
 import javax.swing.*;

 public class ByteIO
 {

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {  
  try
  {
     FileInputStream fis =  new FileInputStream("BaseballNames1.csv");
     BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
     DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);

     while(dis.available() > 0)
     {
        String header = (dis.readUTF());

        String firstName = (dis.readUTF());
        String lastName = (dis.readUTF());
        String fullName = (firstName + " " + lastName);

        int birthDay = (dis.readInt());
        int birthMonth = (dis.readInt());
        int birthYear = (dis.readInt());
        String birthDate = (birthMonth + "/" + birthDay + "/" + birthYear);  

        int weight = (dis.readInt());
        double height = (dis.readDouble());

        System.out.println( header + fullName + birthDate + weight + height);

        dis.close();
     }
  }
  catch(EOFException eof)
  {
     System.out.println("End of File!");
  }
  catch(FileNotFoundException fe)
  {
     System.out.println("File not found!");
  }
  catch(IOException ie)
  {
     ie.printStackTrace();
  }    
 }
}
```

Comment: What does your file look like? Since you're getting Strings out of it, smells like it should be a text file, and if so, use a Reader or Scanner, not a DataInputStream. Please display a goodly portion of your data file.

Comment: And `EOFException` is not really a 'runtime-error' either. Please be more accurate with your tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that your file is not a binary data file, but rather is filled with text. If so, use a Scanner or a Reader such as a FileReader wrapped in a BufferedReader, not a DataInputStream.

Edit: it's a CSV file, so of course it's text!
You'll probably want to use a CSV parser as well as a BufferedReader or Scanner.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't write the file with `writeUTF(),` so`readUTF()` can't read it. See the Javadoc. A CSV file is text, not what results from `writeUTF().`